# TexStudio auto-detected wrong-spelled words

Tags: texstudio, spelling, dictionaries

Some words (not keywords but simply text) are not recognized as correct-English-spelled by TexStudio and the program automatically underlines them in red. For example:

[image]

Questions:

- I guess Texstudio has a dictionary or something like that. How to add or remove words from it?
- Is there a way of listing all the auto-detected wrong-spelled words within the text? (for example, at the end of a compilation)